# How many people have worn the straw hat, if only for a second?

Tags: one-piece

How many people have worn Luffy's straw hat? Canon, confirmed, and on the head (I'm counting Robin even if she wore it atop of her other cowboy hat).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Here](http://www.comicvine.com/luffys-straw-hat/4055-57348/) you can read who had worn the straw hat and what it has gone through during the series. I will summarize the list here and add proof from the manga. For the complete panel the thumbnails are cut from, click the thumbnails. Until chapter 801,  **it seems 7 people were seen wearing the hat.**

[image]

- Chapter 2 − Monkey D. Luffy

  > Luffy is the current holder of the straw hat.

[image]

- Chapter 1 − Shanks

  > He gave it to Luffy as a young boy after he said the same words that Gold Roger, his former captain, had once said.

[image]

- Chapter 603 − Gol D. Roger

  > Much later in the series, it was revealed that Gold Roger, the man who would become the pirate king, had owned that hat.

[image]

- Chapter 81 − Nami

  > She is the member of Luffy's crew that he more often gives it over to for save keeping.

[image]

- Chapter 114 − Robin
  Not mentioned on the list, but as explained by OP, Robin had taken Luffy's hat from him during their first encounter.

[image]

- Chapter 314 − Usopp

  > Usopp briefly wore the straw hat during the Davy Back Fight against the Foxy Pirates.

[image]

- Chapter 515 − Sweet Pea

  > Luffy was in a panic when he couldn't find his hat, but it saw one of the women in the crown watching him wearing hit.

Comment: In addition to the existing answer, in chapter 912, Tama from Wano also wore it, making her the 8th person who has worn the straw hat.